# How to do 2d interpolation in a grid for a list of points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

It seems a few relevant questions here didn't give me the answer I want.

So I have a 2D look up table which is a 2D grid with values at grid coordiates. For example, such table can be generated by code below:

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(100), np.arange(100))
zz = some_function(xx, yy)
```

now I have a list of coordinates of scattered points on the grid, for example, I can generate such coordinates by:

```
xs = np.random.rand(10) * 100
ys = np.random.rand(10) * 100

scattered_points = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(xs, ys)]
```

How can I interpolate out the z value for these 10 points?
I only find out that I can do this by searching the neighboring grid points of (x, y) and perform interpolation there. It is fine for a few points but I just wonder if there is a better/pythonic way to do that using `numpy`/`scipy`.

Comment: Have you tried `interp2d` from `scipy.interpolate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for what you describe. (Updated)

```py
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
import numpy as np

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(100), np.arange(100))
zz = some_function(xx,yy)

f = interp2d(xx, yy, zz, kind='cubic')

xs = np.random.rand(10) * 100
ys = np.random.rand(10) * 100
zs = np.zeros_like(xs)

for i in range(xs.shape[0]):
    zs[i]=f(xs[i],ys[i])
```

Comment: it actually does not work as expected, it basically generate a 10x10 grid using 10 xs and 10 ys, thus what it returns is a zs of size 10x10, not of size 10

Comment: Updated the code to do (hopefully) what you describe.

Comment: that will work but performance won't be nice... i was looking for a way to vectorize it without loops 'cus i was trying to interpolate millions of points... Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

This uses an internal loop, but it is short and direct:

```
scattered_points = np.squeeze([f(x, y) for x, y in zip(xs, ys)])
```

The `np.squeeze()` is to match the dimensions of the input.